# Issue while adding SPFx web part to app catalog

Tags: web-part, spfx

I have adding SPFx web part to my site by adding .sppkg file to app catalog. Upto 4 days back it was worked fine. But all of sudden from yesterday web part is not visible on page. When I try to find the SPFx app in modern view, I am not able to find the web part. But if i see the site contents page in classic view web part is appearing. I have tried to remove the web part, it almost took 20 hrs to get deleted.
I thought something was wrong here. So I decided to add same web part with newer version. But while adding it is giving me following error.
[image]
If I do gulp serve then in workbench it is working fine. Not in production.
I am using `gulp bundle --ship` and `gulp package-solution --ship` commands to generate the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is currently an outage that prevents you from uploading/adding/removing apps.

For more info:

[Can't install or activate SharePoint add-ins or SharePoint Framework solutions](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/servicehealth)

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to admin portal. Could you please put a screenshot of the message that you are seeing?

Comment: Sure! Added images of original service message and latest update.

Comment: Is this applicable to all? Because just now i have created a trail tenant. There I am not able to see such message under service health.

Comment: It says "North America, Europe / Middle East / Africa, Asia-Pacific, South America, Australia, Japan, Canada, United Kingdom, India, Korea, Microsoft IT", so I assume it's basically everyone.

Comment: Yes. I am from India. But not able to see such message in trail tenant. Any how this is helpful. So update on this issue will be informed by 7th Feb 2018 right!